# Missing Projects in eclipse Server

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

Installed Eclipse Galileo with Java EE IDE and configured Tomcat-6. There are several projects in workspace which i am not able to deploy with tomcat.

`I right-click on Tomcat (in the Servers view) -> Add and remove... ->` a window appears in which there are two textbox
`1. available and 2. Configured`.
i can not see any project in available text-box, Why ? is there anything i am missing to install/configure? Please see below the image

[image]

Comment: There's [no need to put a tag in the title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), if you wonder why I changed your title.

Comment: as viewing in screen your project is simple java project and not dynamic web project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your project are not typed as web app otherwise you would have a little globe on project.
Check your project facets

Comment: No problem, if it's ok for you, validate the answer to close the question ;)